# Regular Expression to check File type

Tags: regex

I am not an expert of Regexp literally but I got a regex which is for file matching in the source of one site, but it's not matching any file.
The expression is:

```
"^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\\\{2}\\w+)\\$?)(\\\\(\\w[\\w].*))+(.jpg|.JPG|.jpeg|.JPEG)$";
```

Is there any expression which matches or qualifies the test of above regexp.

Please Help.
Thank You

Comment: How is the regex used? What is the input string and expected output?

Comment: I looks like it is for matching file name like abc.jpeg or something.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: It's in Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that it is in javascript so to test it on a tester, you need to replace `\\` by a single `\`.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but here are some examples of paths that will match your regex : https://regex101.com/r/Gso9Yx/2

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying it a bit.

`[\w,\s-]+(\.jpe?g|\.JPE?G)$`

Comment: Even simpler? [\w,\s]+(?i)(.jpe?g)$

Comment: You have to escaped the dot. Why have you added comma, spaces and dash, there're not used in OP's regex?

Comment: @Toto No this is just to test a valid filename - which might have been what he needed. So in that case dashes spaces and commas are in there.